# Laravel : Can not insert data into database

Tags: php, laravel

I Have a problem in inserting data into database using eloquent model insertion. I tried
`Model->save()` and `Model::create` and it didn't help me ... also i defined fillable Attributes on my model but it didn't work.

Note: I can retrieve data from DB using `::all()` or `::find` and i can also delete data but i can not insert any data into DB.

**My Model Code is:**

```
<?php
  class Game extends Eloquent{
  protected $table = 'games';
  protected $fillable = array('title','year');
}
```

**My Controller Code is:**

```
<?php

class GameController extends BaseController{
public function doit(){
    $g= new Game;
    $g->title='Xina';
    $g->year='2014';
    //the error occur here
    $g->save();
    //also
    //Game::create(array('title='Xina','year'='2014'));
    //will give an error
    }
  }
```

any one could help me? when i tried my code the only error message i got is:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: Check the Laravel Error Log (in `/path/to/your/site/app/storage/logs/`) for the error message.

Comment: First of all, you should change to development mode in app/app.php, then you will get an error message you can work with. Change the line 'debug' => false, to 'debug' => true, - The error message will then tell you exactly what is going wrong

Comment: Might also be helpful to see what your `games` table looks like. Maybe there's a required field missing or sumpn

Comment: Change your config settings in app.php. change 'debug' => false, to true and see what the error says then.

Comment: i changed the debug to true and i got this error message:

Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S22)

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `games` (`title`, `year`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Xina, 2014, 2014-12-24 00:03:27, 2014-12-24 00:03:27))

Comment: Sounds like you don't have updated_at or created_at defined on your table, try setting: "public $timestamps = false;" on the model.

Comment: Thank you man .. it works by adding $timestamps = false; on the Game model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error:

```
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S22) SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into games (title, year, updated_at, created_at) values (Xina, 2014, 2014-12-24 00:03:27, 2014-12-24 00:03:27))
```

You do not have the Laravel Timestamp columns set on your table.

Stop it checking/setting these columns by setting the timestamps property to false on the model:

```
$timestamps = false;
```